# YouTube Data API (v3): Getting video source url

Tags: video, youtube

For an application I want to get the video source files(mp4, 3gp, flv, different resolutions...) that are provided for a specific youtube video.

These urls normally look like this:

```
http://r3---sn-4g57knle.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&fexp=900245%2C908586%2C924638%2C927622%2C930666%2C930672%2C931983%2C932404%2C934030%2C935664%2C945250%2C946022%2C947209%2C947225%2C952302%2C955103&ip=87.177.189.18&key=yt5&initcwndbps=681250&upn=X4vk4QMCQz0&source=youtube&mm=31&nh=IgpwcjAxLmZyYTA1KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&id=o-AL7s5KXNMvYaMHLpLcWIlhPmCHFPFUsGva5dqMRyHvwA&ms=au&mt=1413583948&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mv=m&expire=1413605670&sver=3&signature=582FD84BF598E08232608193010E2090E528F9F2.F79985AC148D30F08B7FF52643D2366347DED9F3&itag=36
```

Does sombody know if this possibly with the given API. The following call will only give me these information:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=AIzaSyAR8hEPiEkKI8pWSG9oDXMVfe_C6Uh80n8&part=status,snippet,player
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/Zneg4lPSgXR0L-TSvyF64urNwpA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/MVQzBWrYyN1JHf2r72_T20nEM4E\"",
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-06-20T23:12:38.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
    "description": "Antonio Fuentes speaks to us and takes questions on working with Google APIs and OAuth 2.0.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Google Developers",
    "categoryId": "28",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   },
   "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "processed",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true
   },
   "player": {
    "embedHtml": "\u003ciframe type='text/html' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/7lCDEYXw3mM' width='640' height='360' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='true'/\u003e"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: It is definitely not possible, and a violation of YouTube TOS. See http://superuser.com/q/773719 for workaround

Comment: @StevenPenny Then why do they expose it with get_video_info which was their v2 api.

Comment: yes it is possible..

Comment: i have done is using regex

Comment: @user31231234124 how do you get video url using api?

Comment: use regex man...its quite simple

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution to parse those urls and print them out. Maybe also interesting for people out there is the mime-type and the itag.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // URL
        URL youtubeUrl = new URL("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbjg1CkX0As");

        // Open URL
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(youtubeUrl.openStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        String content = builder.toString();

        // Parse URLs
        String[] list = content.split("url=");
        HashSet<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String hits : list) {
            if (hits.startsWith("https")) {
                String link = hits.split(",")[0];
                results.add(link);
            }
        }

        String url = null;
        String itag;
        String type;

        for (String set : results) {
            set = set.replace("\\", "\\\\");

            for (String sdata : set.split("\\\\")) {
                if (sdata.startsWith("https"))
                    url = sdata;
            }

            if (url != null) {
                if (url.startsWith("https")) {
                    url = url.split(" ")[0];
                    url = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");

                    System.out.println("Stream-URL: " + url.toString());

                    if (url.contains("mime=")) {
                        type = (url.split("mime=")[1]).split("&")[0];
                        type = URLDecoder.decode(type, "UTF-8");
                        System.out.println("Mime-Type: " + type);
                    }

                    if (url.contains("itag")) {
                        itag = (url.split("itag=")[1]).split("&")[0];
                        itag = URLDecoder.decode(itag, "UTF-8");
                        System.out.println("itag: " + itag);
                    }

                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<title>(.*?)</title>");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
                    while (m.find() == true) {
                        String htmlTitle = m.group(1);
                        htmlTitle = htmlTitle.substring(0, htmlTitle.length() - 10);
                        htmlTitle = URLDecoder.decode(htmlTitle);
                        System.out.println("Title: " + htmlTitle);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This standalone script will print out the following:

```
Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.521&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&keepalive=yes&signature=DC485AFB3956E6F065BF3A2363187F47A392AFFA.8F137502456DB32C7B99D91EE0E6AE77116499A9&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408633524115186&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=216513824&mv=m&itag=251&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=audio%2Fwebm&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: audio/webm
itag: 251
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.576&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&keepalive=yes&signature=CDD2A5E66D7CCFA2FDEA03D02E9B21B613A76A08.74B909CEC39528AB3FACCC5F694908F13F733A7B&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408762859064032&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=179669295&mv=m&itag=140&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=audio%2Fmp4&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: audio/mp4
itag: 140
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbjg1CkX0As&amp;format=xml"
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.441&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&keepalive=yes&signature=DA6900416026AD7E2DBB0D24DBBCD4CF0FC36FD0.D440569A1E63C9BF085EEB395AF1A793C46D6575&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408762998859604&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=153850123&mv=m&itag=160&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=video%2Fmp4&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: video/mp4
itag: 160
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.529&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&keepalive=yes&signature=068AC8C88659E40BA11BDAC4A08D494602492C07.8E23D8690A89ECE26BD145D2D7A7E5D52F1DCC44&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408633512497831&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=134335071&mv=m&itag=171&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=audio%2Fwebm&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: audio/webm
itag: 171
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.441&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&keepalive=yes&signature=0B4E9BEAB22A21CBC5DD9152ECCA2E5626A77B2B.37038F6342DE259E3845657C7446A5877E8ADB40&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408762859400512&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=341375567&mv=m&itag=133&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=video%2Fmp4&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: video/mp4
itag: 133
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.739&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&signature=5B6F6EBBC26356D5EA09305BB9943329E9799594.76406956D7019C08B0442CE5022ABECD26E050B2&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1402746302320112&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=315994974&mv=m&itag=36&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=video%2F3gpp&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: video/3gpp
itag: 36
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.480&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&keepalive=yes&signature=600297F5AE56AD894F576C42435126AF5DC92250.ACF694661F71924F18DB33293CDE904E8D8DF819&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408636410543086&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=221807998&mv=m&itag=242&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=video%2Fwebm&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: video/webm
itag: 242
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.576&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&signature=BF5FD0028DB0E0CCBFA4F793E2DD14C40EF27260.A828539A9E99B3270E87CB52D354F3B9414F1473&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408763244110396&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=587648380&mv=m&ratebypass=yes&itag=18&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=video%2Fmp4&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: video/mp4
itag: 18
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.521&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&keepalive=yes&signature=2FE1F940A3683F82F334E53FFF01B22A493B4ECF.843617DDE77CE2928EC2394F6539AC369EA3D29C&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408633517569061&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=65323057&mv=m&itag=249&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=audio%2Fwebm&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: audio/webm
itag: 249
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.521&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&keepalive=yes&signature=8A5BC896960E448A63E47588896B3EACF1F9A66C.5811D670190E5D8868CCE217C46160A4962AE79C&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408633513830627&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=80572787&mv=m&itag=250&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=audio%2Fwebm&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: audio/webm
itag: 250
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.520&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&keepalive=yes&signature=AF988FC4C3BB7B3DF2D099885625CF11C10071BF.061CFA4288DB323C11131F2014D7EA0B337C1885&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1408634899442262&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=92548106&mv=m&itag=278&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=video%2Fwebm&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: video/webm
itag: 278
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=11191.785&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&signature=32AF551C5DE2593EF7B12ECEF5C5A9D0F2960D69.CBB13585C8B2B1EE42BDFAF99575D63B25ACA7DA&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1402744752653433&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=113602023&mv=m&itag=17&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=video%2F3gpp&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B"
Mime-Type: video/3gpp
itag: 17
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://r6---sn-4g5e6n7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=0.000&ei=_slyWInMFIjBWoLKlogN&mn=sn-4g5e6n7r&mm=31&key=yt6&ip=46.5.2.116&signature=72B7D5F55A9D85FB4FD716217463096511BDB78E.3DEDD0D885FB7EF84E16CCA241DEC6902CBF6D58&initcwndbps=1150000&gir=yes&mt=1483917673&ms=au&ipbits=0&lmt=1402760337253038&upn=GUSCKRIivU0&pl=17&source=youtube&clen=997314522&mv=m&ratebypass=yes&itag=43&nh=IgpwcjA1LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mime=video%2Fwebm&expire=1483939422&id=o-AJNwZexTfaj7RaRcA8HeiWWa2oUKD0Sasrh8WqpZ5I0B
Mime-Type: video/webm
itag: 43
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)

Stream-URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbjg1CkX0As&amp;format=json"
Title: Karlsruher SC -  FC Valencia 02.11.1993 (7:0)
```

Comment: Does not work anymore:

Stream-URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbjg1CkX0As"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:73)